# catch DB exception in JSF+EJB application

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa, jsf-2, ejb

I'm using Glassfish 3.1 with JSF2 and EJB stateless to query and write an Oracle DB. The table the user wants to populate in this web application has a primary key. When the user tries to add a new record the ejb method invoking em.persist is called. Now, if the user tries to add a record that has an already used primary key value, I got an exception in the EJB.
I would like to pop up a message to the user indicating that an error in the database occurred but I can't figure out how the JSF managed bean could catch the EJB exception.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EJB has the concept of system exceptions and application exceptions.

Runtime exceptions, like `EntityExistsException` are system exceptions. These will among others cause any transaction to be rolled-ed back and cause the EJB instance bean to be discarded (destroyed). Most importantly for your problem, they will be wrapped in an `EJBException`.

There is no magic surrounding catching these exceptions. Adjusting the code from Petr above,
the following will just work:

Backing bean:

```
@EJB
private DAOBean daoBean;

public void savePerson(Entity e) {
     try {
         daoBean.save(e);
     } catch (EJBException e) {         
         FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("entity is already exists.");
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance.addMessage(null, message);
     }         
}
```

EJB:

```
private EntityManager em;

public void save(Entity e) {    
    em.persist(e);    
}
```

Note that you can retrieve the cause of the exception to see if was an `EntityExistsException` or not (omitted above for brevity).

Since you probably have no need to destroy your EJB instance for this case, a better pattern is to define your own exception that inherits from a `RuntimeException` and is annotated with the `@ApplicationException` with the `rollback` attribute set to true.

E.g.

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {

    public MyException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

Wrap your `EntityExistsException` in your EJB into this exception and throw and catch it.

I strongly advise you **NOT** to use error codes or boolean success/failure as a result. This is a well-known anti pattern and makes your code incredible error prone.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I wasn't sure how is this works. BTW, thats why I wrote as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom exception class. Let's say `UserException` with a enum values of possible exception option.

In you EJB you can define your methods as throwable. If you need throw a exception.

In your JSF-SiteBean you only need to use a simple try/catch.

Is exception from type UserException ... get enum reason ... etc.